# com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException on Weblogic 12.2.1.3

Tags: java, serialization, jackson, weblogic, jackson-databind

An error has occurred during serialization.

I try update jackson lib (2.4 -> 2.7), add com.fasterxml.* into prefer-application-packages in weblogic-application.xml, call setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL) for objectMapper.

But error was not solved.

Object com.packagename.SavedAction from stacktrace is not null and hasn't null fields.

```
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: (was java.lang.NullPointerException) (through reference chain: com.packagename.SavedAction[0])
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:391)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:363)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.StdSerializer.wrapAndThrow(StdSerializer.java:338)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.ObjectArraySerializer.serializeTypedContents(ObjectArraySerializer.java:304)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.ObjectArraySerializer.serializeContents(ObjectArraySerializer.java:226)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.ObjectArraySerializer.serialize(ObjectArraySerializer.java:210)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.ObjectArraySerializer.serialize(ObjectArraySerializer.java:22)
at com.mypackaggename.core.json.SaveJsonSerializer.serialize(SaveJsonSerializerSerializer.java:65)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider._serialize(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:480)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:319)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter$Prefetch.serialize(ObjectWriter.java:1396)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter._configAndWriteValue(ObjectWriter.java:1120)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter.writeValueAsString(ObjectWriter.java:993)
at com.mypackagename.core.json.ConfiguratedPacker.pack(ConfiguratedPacker.java:63)
at com.mypackagename.core.json.JPHandler.pack(JPHandler.java:86)
... 69 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.TypeSerializer.typeId(TypeSerializer.java:79)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase._typeIdDef(BeanSerializerBase.java:679)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeWithType(BeanSerializerBase.java:599)
at com.mypackaggename.core.json.SaveJsonSerializer.serializeWithType(SaveJsonSerializer.java:110)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.ObjectArraySerializer.serializeTypedContents(ObjectArraySerializer.java:301)
... 80 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that WLS ignore prefer-application-packages option and has your own jackson lib version.
The link to xmlns spec was changed.

before:

xmlns="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/90"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/90 http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/90/weblogic-application.xsd"

after:

xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-application" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-application http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-application/1.3/weblogic-application.xsd"

After that the error was solved.